# How to compute the integral of $\int \sin(1-x^2)\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

I tried substitution,  $u=1-x^2,\, du =  -2x\,dx ,\, dx = -\frac{du}{2x}$, yielding:

\begin{align}
& \int \sin u \left(-\frac{du} 2 \right) \\[10pt]
= {} & -\frac{1}{2}\int \sin(u)\,du \\[10pt]
= {} & -\frac{1}{2}\cos u \\[10pt]
= {} & -\frac{1}{2}\cos (1-x^2)
\end{align}

[WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20sin(1-x%5E2)) is showing something completely different, however. What's wrong with my solution?

Comment: $dx=-\frac{du}{2x}$ is correct, but you didn't use this in the next line

Comment: @woofy I just factored it, shouldn't we do that with constants?

Comment: Where did the $x$ go?

Comment: $$\int{\sin{(1-x^{2})}}dx=\sin{(1)}\int\cos{(x^{2})}dx+\cos{(1)}\int\sin{(x^{2})}dx$$
Now you can use the fact that
$$\int{e^{ix^{n}}dx}=x_{1}F_{1}\Big(\frac{1}{n}, 1+\frac{1}{n}, ix^{n}\Big)$$

Comment: @woofy can I factor $\frac{1}{2}*x$ then?

Comment: No, you can't take the $x$ outside. The substitution you have tried won't help with this integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your substitution is wrong.

Set $$1 - x^2 = a ~~~~~~~ dx = \frac{-1}{2 \sqrt{1 - a}} da$$

Hence

$$-\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{\sin(a)\ da}{\sqrt{1 - a}}$$

Elementary knowledge of analysis tell you that this is a Fresnel Type integral, and the solution can be written as

$$-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2 \pi }\cos(1) \left( S\left(\frac{\sqrt{2-2 x}}{\sqrt{\pi }}\right)-\cot(1) C\left(\frac{\sqrt{2-2 x}}{\sqrt{\pi }}\right)\right)$$

Where $S$ and $C$ stand for "Fresnel Sine and Cosine Integral"

Cot stands for the co-tangent.

**More on Fresnel Integrals:**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral

Comment: How did $\frac{-1}{2 \sqrt{1 - a}} da$ become  $-\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{\sin(a)\ da}{\sqrt{1 - a}}$?

Comment: Integration by substitution. You had a sine before, you have to maintain the sine after. Also the $-1/2$ constant has been taken out

Answer (score 0):

$\int\sin(1-x^2)~dx$

$=\sin1\int\cos x^2~dx-\cos1\int\sin x^2~dx$

$=\sqrt{\dfrac{\pi}{2}}\left(\sin1~C\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{\pi}}x\right)-\cos1~S\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{\pi}}x\right)\right)+C$ (according to http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FresnelIntegrals.html)